# Gwt Raw Html content using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have below the html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert($("#aaa").html());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="aaa">

<button>hello</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<input type="text" name="textt"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Now on click of `hello` button, i need to get raw html content.

It gives below output.

```
<button>Change content of all p elements</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<input name="textt" type="text">
```

But notice the output. The end tag for input is missing. How can i get exact raw content of html without missing end tag of `input`?

I am expecting below output.

```
<button>Change content of all p elements</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<input name="textt" type="text"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: an input element does not require an end tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still I need an end tag like </input> because raw html is an input for XML parser Else XML parser complains that input has no end tag..That is why i need it.

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert($("#aaa").html() +"</input>");
  });
});
```